# fast way to rotate a matrix about its current position

Tags: c++, opengl, matrix, linear-algebra, coordinate-transformation

If I have a matrix then the point O(0,0,0) will be translated to some point P(x, y, z). So rotating a matrix about its current position is effectively multiplying the matrix by a rotation matrix about P.

So I want a function like:

```
mat4 rotate(mat4 matrix, vec3 axis, float angle);
```

my current idea is:

```
vec4 p = {0, 0, 0, 1};

p = p * matrix;

generate translation matrix T, from point p

generate rotation matrix R, from axis and angle

return matrix * T * R * -T;
```

but I feel like there should be a more efficient way to do this...

Comment: Not really, that's the way I'd do it.

Comment: Multiplying a matrix by (0,0,0) yields (0,0,0).

Comment: @beta but its not (0, 0, 0) its (0, 0, 0, 1) since its a point

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yep, that's how I'd do it. But one subtle correction, reverse the order of `-T` and `T`:

```
  return matrix * -T * R * T
```

You want to *first* 'undo' the translational origin of `matrix`, *then* rotate, *then* re-do translational origin. This is easier to see if you take, for example, a traditional scale/rotate/translate matrix (`S * R2 * T`), expand it, then you can see more easily:

```
  (S * R2 * T) * -T * R * T
```

Is doing what you want.

EDIT: With respect to efficiency, totally depends on usage. No, this is not 'great' -- usually you have more information about `matrix` that will allow you to do this in a less round-about way. E.g., if the matrix is constructed from `S * R * T` above, obviously we could have simply changed the way that the matrix is constructed in the first place -- `S * R2 * R * T`, injecting the rotation where it should be without having to 'undo' anything.

But unless you are doing this in real-time on 10K+ matrix *that need to be recomputed each time*, then it should not be a problem.

If `matrix` is coming from an unknown source and you need to modify it ex-post-facto, indeed, there really isn't any other choice.

Answer (score 1):

In common an transformation matrix (OpenGL/glsl/glm) is defined like this:

```
mat4 m44 = mat4(
    vec4( Xx, Xy, Xz, 0.0),   // x-axis
    vec4( Yx, Xy, Yz, 0.0),   // y-axis
    vec4( Zx, Zy, Zz, 0.0),   // z-axis
    vec4( Tx, Ty, Tz, 1.0)    // translation
);
```

A translation matrix looks like this:

```
mat4 translate = mat4(
    vec4( 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0),
    vec4( 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0),   
    vec4( 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0),  
    vec4( Tx,  Ty,  Tz,  1.0)
);
```

And a rotation matrix (e.g. around Y-Axis) looks like this:

```
float angle;
mat4 rotate = mat4(
    vec4( cos(angle),  0, sin(angle), 0 ),
    vec4( 0,           1, 0,          0 ),
    vec4( -sin(angle), 0, cos(angle), 0 ),
    vec4( 0,           0, 0,          1 )
);
```

A matrix multiplication `C = A * B` works like this:

```
mat4 A, B, C;

// C = A * B
for ( int k = 0; k < 4; ++ k )
    for ( int j = 0; j < 4; ++ j )
        C[k][j] = A[0][l] * B[k][0] + A[1][j] * B[k][1] + A[2][j] * B[k][2] +  A[3][j] * B[k][3];
```

This means that the result of `translate * rotate` is:

```
mat4 m = mat4(
    vec4( cos(angle),  0,  sin(angle), 0 ),
    vec4( 0,           1,  0,          0 ),
    vec4( -sin(angle), 0,  cos(angle), 0 ),
    vec4( tx,          ty, tz,         1 )
);
```

[image]

This means if you want to rotate a matrix `M` around its origin, then you have to split the matrix in a "oriantation" matrix and a "translation" matrtix. Rotate the orientation matrix and add the translation matrix again:

```
mat4 M, R;

float Tx = M[3][0];
float Ty = M[3][1];
float Tz = M[3][2];

M[3][0] = 0.0; M[3][1] = 0.0; M[3][2] = 0.0;

mat4 MR = R * M;
MR[3][0] = Tx; MR[3][1] = Ty; M[3][2] = Tz;
```